# How to replace placeholder for localized string

Tags: javascript

I have localization file (en.json). I have a string in which there is a placeholder with symbol % (%time) that I want to replace when sending a message to the user. But in the documentation of botframework js v3 I could not find how to do this.

I can move this string in constants likes usual JS string and replace placeholder.

```
{
  "workplace_quick_reminder": "Hurry up! You`re booking will be canceled at %time if you don`t check in.",
}
```

I want to replace %time placeholder likes 11:52 or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. This all about how you strategies approach. It has nothing to do with framework. Plain JavaScript function could do.

You want to replace using framework only? botframework ? You dont want to do with normal javascript replace?

Comment: Thanks for answer. So: 
1. yes, i want to just use framework only, 
2.  yes.
3. yes.
But I found solution for my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58078901/11119413

Answer (score 0):

For my current approach I just need to pass in session.endConversation as second param a string replacer.
For example:

```
{
  "workplace_quick_reminder": "Hurry up! You`re booking will be canceled at %s if you don`t check in.",
}

const stringReplacer = 'something'
session.endConversation('workplace_quick_reminder', stringReplacer);
```